# How to properly make an object own another polymorphic object?

Tags: c++, pointers, move-semantics, unique-ptr, ownership

I'm looking for a save and clean way of how to make an object own another (polymorphic!) object, that it gets initialized with in the constructor.
Additionally I want to make it accessible with a getter.

After scanning several blogs and posts on SO, I assume this is best done using `std::unique_ptr` and figured out this:

```
#include <memory>

class owned {};

class owner {
    const std::unique_ptr<const owned> m_owned;
public:
    owner(std::unique_ptr<const owned>&& o) : m_owned{ std::move(o) } {}
    const owned& owned() const { return *m_owned; }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<owned> _owned{ std::make_unique<owned>(owned()) };
    owner _owner(std::move(_owned));
}
```

However, I am not very familiar with the very details of `std::unique_ptr` and thus unsure, whether that's a good way to realize my idea. Especially the double use of `std::move` makes me doubt...

**So the question:** Is this the preferred way of transferring a polymorphic object's ownership to another object and making it accessible? If not, what *is* the best way to do so?

Comment: That's a reasonable way of doing it.  Makes owner a bit awkward (such as trying to stick it in a vector), but perhaps that's okay.

Comment: @Eljay Can you clarify what you mean in particular? I do not quite understand.

Comment: One of the unique aspects of C++, that no other programming language has, is that if you get five C++ developers in the room and ask "what is the preferred way to do X", or what is the "best" way to do "Y", where "X" or "Y" can be anything, you will get six different answers. You are the only one who can answer your question. The only way to answer this question is to fully understand all of your requirements, and fully understand the relevant related C++ resources. Therefore, this is something that mostly depends on the information that only you know, and noone on stackoverflow.com does.

Comment: @Sam I ceratinly get your point and experienced it a lot of times here on SO. However that problem/use case seems so common and 'universal' that I expected it'd have some kind of standard solution. You know, in Java I'd just have a member variable of some interface-type that I'd initialize from a parameter in the constructor and wouldn't care about ownership. Now, in C++, I only want to signal, that the constructed object now even _owns_ the passed one and it's (the owned one's) lifetime is now depending on the owning object. That seems like a _very_ very common use case...

Comment: I mean that owner is going to have an implicitly-deleted copy constructor.  So code that relies on using a copy constructor will fail.  And since copy constructor use of objects is pretty common, its sort of like having one hand tied behind your back.  Of course, if needed, you could add back in an explicit copy constructor.

Comment: C++ is not Java. In C++ it is your responsibility to contruct and destruct objects. That results in many design choices that must be made based on the specific requirements of each individual case. No two applications create and destroy objects in exactly the same way, and the "best" approach depends on what exactly needs to be done for ***that*** particular case. If you really wish to understand C++, you will do yourself a favor by forgetting everything you know about Java. Despite a very similar syntax, C++ is a fundamentally different language that works in completely different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine.  I'd drop `&&` in one place:

```
owner(std::unique_ptr<const owned> o) :
```

because it isn't needed.

One gotcha; if you add `owner(owner&&)=default;` then `owned` can sometimes be empty.  So a way to detect that state is good.

Comment: I used the (indeed unnecessary) rvalue reference to force the caller to use `std::move` and thus signal that his passed `unique_ptr` would transfer ownership. However I cannot perfectly judge if this is a common way to do so, thus the question here - so is it?

Comment: You mean, since `owned` might be moved out (due to move construction), I should offer a way to test if the getter's reference is valid? Also isn't the move-constructor implicitly created anway, making `owner(owner&&)=default;` redundant?

Comment: @Reizo • The caller is already forced to use `std::move`, because of the semantics of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Reizo The only difference between `unique_ptr&&` and `unique_ptr` as an argument is that the first one can result in the unique ptr ownership *not* being taken, while the second guarantees that it is.  It is really easy to accidentally disable special member function ctors; I was assuming your code was an example, not final.  My point is that the empty state is possible if you move-from the struct.  And blocking the empty state from being possible is usually a bad idea, as it makes the move-ctor noexcept(false).